# To whom does this coat of arms belong?

Tags: heraldry

[image: The coat of arms]

Does anybody know the armiger of the coat of arms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I flipped the image in Photoshop:

[image: inverted image]

This makes it easier to read the two mottos:

> "SURGE ILLUMINARE JERUSALEM" (Arise, shine, Jerusalem)

and

> "VIDIMUS STELLAM EIUS IN ORIENTE" (We have seen his star in the East)

A quick Google search found a match in [Armorial des prélats français du XIXe siècle](https://archive.org/stream/armorialdesprla00saudgoog#page/n246/mode/2up/search/ejus+in+oriente), p. 232

---

Here, the armorial is identified as belonging to Augustin Cluzel.

The full entry (in French) reads:

> CLUZEL (AUGUSTIN), né à Monelar (Aveyron) le 6 mars 1815, sacré à
>   Paris, Ie 6 Septembre 1874, archevêque titulaire d'Héractée, délégué
>   apostolique en Perse, décédé à Ourmiah (Perse) Ie 12 août 1882.
>
> ARMES. - D'azur à Jésus prêchant au naturel, aliàs d'or, posé sur un
>   tertre de sinople, au chef cousu de gueules chargé d'une étoile
>   (l'étoile des Mages) d'or.
>
> DEVISE. - Surge illuminare Jerusalem
>   (Isaï., LX, 1).Vidimus stellam ejus in Oriente (Math., II, 2), (I)